# Unable to turn kafka stream into flink table

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

I want to make a table out of a kafka stream and print it but getting this trivial errror.

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")

    val src = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[ObjectNode]("broadcast", new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties)
    val stream = env.
      addSource(src)
    val tbl = tEnv.registerDataStream("ASK", stream, 'locationID, 'temp)

    env.execute()
```

Kindly Help, ThankYou

Comment: Did you got any errors ?
please share

Comment: I'm able to convert it now, I've got this error now =>

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321155/org-apache-flink-table-api-tableexception-arity-6-of-result